# Unexpected character encountered while parsing Value asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi

this is i am trying to do but getting this error

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value

```
var searchModel = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmployeeSearchModel>(filter);
```

Model

```
  public class EmployeeSearchModel
     {
         public string EmployeeNameSearch { get; set; } = null;
         public string SearchFilter { get; set; } = null;
     }
```

[Error Detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdmrD.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `filter` is not a valid JSON.

In fact, the exact error can be reproduced by the following code:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("a");
//Error: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: a. Path '', line 0, position 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

> coming string in filter variable

I believe the translation of what you said should be "The incoming filter variable is a string".

---

When receiving this error it can also mean your controller's action method has not been setup to take in a specific class to deserialize to.

For example this will **fail** with your error message:

```
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] string filter)
{
var searchModel = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmployeeSearchModel>(filter);
```

But the following will **succeed** because we have identified a specific object to deserialize and do not have to call Newtonsoft *because .Net Core has deserialized it for us*:

```
 public IActionResult Post([FromBody] EmployeeSearchModel searchModel)
 {
     If (searchModel.EmployeeNameSearch == "OmegaMan") 
         ...
```

So make sure your JSON incoming body is the same as the class.